# Adjusting column width according to Screen Size in DataGridView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have achieved the following till now (Columns are NOT resizing automatically as per the size of the application):

[image: Static Column Widths]

I want to achieve the following so that columns resize dynamically whenever user changes the size of the application:

[image: Dynamic Column Widths]

I am using DataGridView in .Net 2008

Comment: Hello, was the problem solved? I still face this issue with .net 4.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a value for `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode`:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

You can set it in the grid properties at design-time too:

[image]

Comment: But there's one challenge. I want certain columns to not to scale "as much as they are scaling". Bcoz with this method, all columns get the same size. I want certain columns to scale more than others.

Comment: I got a solution. After `dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill`, we can simply loop through number of columns and add `Col.Width = Col.GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeader, True)`. This adjusts the size automatically as per the columns widths

Comment: @IshGoel I tried to loop through the columns, But i am getting "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}". AM i missing something.

Comment: Here is the code
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridEmailListView.Columns)
            {
                col.Width = col.GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeader, true);
            }